# Xamarin Forms Labs Camera - Permanently Saving Images and Calling Them

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got the camera function to work and it displays the image on the page like i asked it too. But is there a way to permanently save the image on your phone or somewhere else and then call it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code that works for me.

`IFileAccess` is my wrapper around `System.IO.File` functions such as file open, write, check if exsists. If you're making your own file service look up `Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Resolver` and how to use it; if you're using shared Forms project type you can access System.IO.File directly from the Forms project. Assuming that's clear, the following

```
var fileAccess = Resolver.Resolve<IFileAccess> (); 
mediaPicker.SelectPhotoAsync (new CameraMediaStorageOptions{ MaxPixelDimension = 1024 })
.ContinueWith(t=>{
  if (!t.IsFaulted && !t.IsCanceled) { 
    var mediaFile = t.Result;  

    var fileAccess = Resolver.Resolve<IFileAccess> ();
    string imageName = "IMG_" + DateTime.Now.ToString ("yy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".jpg";

 // save the media stream to a file 
    fileAccess.WriteStream (imageName, mediaFile.Source);

 // use the stored file for ImageSource
    ImageSource imgSource = ImageSource.FromFile (fileAccess.FullPath (imageName)); 

    imgInXAML.Source = imgSource;
  }
});
```

---

Further detail on IFileAccess.

In your Forms project create an interface like this:

```
public interface IFileAccess
{
    bool Exists (string filename);
    string FullPath(string filename); 
    void WriteStream (string filename, Stream streamIn);
}
```

In your iOS or Android or Shared project add a class FileAccess that implements IFileAccess:

```
public class FileAccess : IFileAccess
{ 
    public bool Exists (string filename)
    {
        var filePath = GetFilePath (filename);

        if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
            FileInfo finf = new FileInfo (filePath);
            return finf.Length > 0;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public string FullPath (string filename)
    {
        var filePath = GetFilePath (filename);
        return filePath;
    }

    static string GetFilePath (string filename)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, filename);
        return filePath;
    }

    public void WriteStream (string filename, Stream streamIn)
    {
        var filePath = GetFilePath (filename);
        using (var fs = File.Create (filePath)) {
            streamIn.CopyTo (fs); 
        }
    }
}
```

If you're already using Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Resolver then add only the line to register the service, otherwise in your iOS or Android project find a call to `Forms.Init()` and right before it add

```
var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer ();
resolverContainer.Register<IFileAccess> (t => new FileAccess ()); // maybe just this line
Resolver.SetResolver (resolverContainer.GetResolver ());
```

Comment: It says IFileAccess does not exist, and that System.IO.File does not exist in xamarin forms shared project either. Any thoughts?

Comment: as I explained - IFileAccess is one of my interfaces, not a part of Xamarin.Forms

Comment: What if I want to use the Amazon S3 service to save the picture? And also where do i get the IFileAccess wrapper from

PS: I am using Xamarin Forms Shared Project

Thank you

Comment: if you're using S3 you'll need the AWS SDK from Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/amazon  Keep in mind it's not very fresh (2 years old). Alternatively (I actually do that) you can send your file to your own server and then send them from there to S3 - this way you can switch S3 with various other storage services at a whim.  S3 also allows you to make your files public and share them with a link, which you could use to populate an ImageSource

Comment: In either case you can implement the IFileAccess service or similar and keep the storage concern separate from image acquisition

Comment: Your above example worked, but I have a question. The string imageName is the name of the image, where does it save though?

Comment: Look at the implementation of the FileAccess service - there is a call that gets the personal file location: `Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`. You can see what that is by calling `fileAccess.FullPath (imageName)` and outputting the result to the console if you wish

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you are giving me. But one last question, if i want to send the image to the server which will add it to amazonS3, how do i send the image to the server?

fileAccess.FullPath (imageName)?
Which is the location of the image

Or another way?

Comment: So i want to upload it to the server but it needs to be converted to an <input type=file>. Would you happen to know how to do that?

Comment: ask another question or research "c# file upload" or "httpclient post multipart"

Comment: ok i did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191435/xamarin-forms-uploading-files-to-sever