# How to invoke a method located inside the Android project from the Portable Class Library Project in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This might sound a silly question but since I'm quite new to Xamarin, I'll go for it.

So I have a Xamarin.Forms solution and there's an Android project plus a Portable Class Library. I am calling the starting page from the MainActivity.cs inside the Android project which itself calls the first page from the forms defined in Portable Class Library project (by calling App.GetMainPage()). Now, I want to add a click event on one of my forms to get the current location of device. Apparently, to get the location I have to implement it inside the Android project. So how can I call the GetLocation method from my click event inside the Portable Class Library project? Any help would be appreciated. Sorry for possible duplicate.

Comment: Sorry it was duplicate! 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588557/xamarin-forms-get-data-from-device-specific-code-back-to-the-forms?rq=1
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

Answer (score 14):

The solution is indeed in the provided link if you use Xamarin.Forms.Labs. If you only use Xamarin.Forms, it's *almost* the same thing you gotta do by using the DependencyService. It's easier than it seems.
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/

I suggest reading this post where I almost broke my brain trying to understand.
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/95717

For convenience, here's a working example that you could adapt if you didn't already finish your work:

Create an interface in your Xamarin.Forms project.

```
using Klaim.Interfaces;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Klaim.Interfaces
{
    public interface IImageResizer
    {
        byte[] ResizeImage (byte[] imageData, float width, float height);
    }
}
```

Create the service/custom renderer in your Android project.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Klaim.Interfaces;
using Klaim.Droid.Renderers;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (ImageResizer_Android))]
namespace Klaim.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class ImageResizer_Android : IImageResizer
    {
        public ImageResizer_Android () {}
        public byte[] ResizeImage (byte[] imageData, float width, float height)
        {

            // Load the bitmap
            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)width, (int)height, false);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                resizedImage.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
                return ms.ToArray ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when you call this:

```
byte[] test = DependencyService.Get<IImageResizer>().ResizeImage(AByteArrayHereCauseFun, 400, 400);
```

It executes Android code and returns the value into your Forms project.