# How to upload a photo to a webservice using Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to upload a photo to my data base using Xamarin forms. I have the image. How would I use HTTP Post to push it up to the web service?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185903/xamarin-forms-labs-camera-permanently-saving-images-and-calling-them/25186674#25186674
After you save the file you can research "multipart post file"

Answer (score -1):

First: write code to covert your image to base64 string.
Second: Pass this string to your web service using HTTP Post.
third: in your web service write code to convert this base64 string to image.
fourth: store that image in your server directory

Comment: What a horrible idea to convert the image to B64!

Comment: @Sten Petrov Would you like to be constructive please? Okay not B64. So what then?

Comment: @StenPetrov I accepts that there may be other ideas to do this. Can you please describe why it is horrible?

Comment: @MiralBhalani there's no reason *generally* to B64 an image and add 30% bulk of data. There *are* some legit reason I can think of but they'd involve JS, not Xamarin. From Xamarin you do binary Post. To top it off your answer isn't an answer, really, it's a comment - there is no technical know-how that could help the OP